# search an element in a string using Pattern and matcher in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to search an element in a string using Pattern and matcher in Java.

i have a node variant-items and need to get all the characters coming between these nodes.
i tried the below regex but it is skipping this line altogether.
however if i search using the same regex in Notepad++ i am getting the desired resulted selected. please advice.

```
<variant-items>((.|\n)*)</variant-items>
```

Below is my implemenation

```
String patternSourceComponent = "<variant-items>((.|\n)*)</variant-items>";
            String result=this.isMatched(patternSourceComponent, xml);

public String isMatched(String patternSourceComponent,String xml)
    {
    String varientItem="";
    try{    Pattern patternComponent = Pattern.compile(patternSourceComponent);
            Matcher matcherComponent = patternComponent.matcher(xml);

            System.out.println("matcherComponent Find : "+matcherComponent.find());
           while (matcherComponent.find()) {
               varientItem=matcherComponent.group(0).trim();
               System.out.println("varientItem : "+varientItem);
           }   }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
            }

    return varientItem;
    }
```

Comment: you need to escape some characters while using in java '\' is one of them

Comment: You shouldn't parse XML with regular expressions ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/896588 ), use a proper XML parser like JDOM instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use Java [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) to checks your nodes. Using regex for XML is a nightmare, and any code attempting it is very likely to break in the future. Try something like this to get the string contents of your 'variant-items' nodes.

```
File xmlFile = new File("your_xml.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("variant-items");
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nList.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getNodeValue()); 
}
```

The above code prints the values of all 'variant-items' nodes in an xml file.

If resources/speed considerations are an issue (like when your_xml.xml is huge), you might be better off using [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html), which is faster (a little more code intensive) and doesn't store the XML in memory.

Comment: in the above i am already using a parser to parse and then convert it into a String. my requirement is to find if this regular expression is present in the String variable i get.

Comment: @AjayMuraleedharan - If that's the case, why don't you check with your parser **before** you convert it to a string?